# My ISP is injecting a swf into my webpage. How legal is this?

Tags: injection

I recently saw a pop-up, on a http page. It was the advertisement of some offers provided by the ISP.

Here is the code:

```
<td>
  <object width="480" height="195" data="<url>/V3/front_porch_RAN.swf" style="pointer-events:none;>...</object>
</td>
```

There is no javascript that is collecting my data, but is indulging in the activity of injecting code into the webpage, legal?

Edit: I live in India.

Comment: You're may not get a definite answer to a legal question like this, but you're really unlikely to get it if you don't mention what country you live in :)

Comment: This may be more appropriate for [Law.SE]. I'm not certain though. Either way it probably depends on the contract between the ISP and the owner of the website.

Comment: Hmm... Edited the post and will post it in law too. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: this is the first Google hit: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/06/10/israeli_ad_slingers_gagging_order_indian_techie/

Comment: It is a reason to move to another ISP very, very fast...